# C# array is not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create a basic weather app where you can enter readings for a city and it will display the average, lowest temperature and highest temperature.

I created a 2d array (intTemps) with 5 rows (citys) and 4 columns (4 readings). Whenever I add a temperature to the listbox, it always displays in the upper left. When I add another temperature, it displays the same temperature that was just displayed and the current temperature.

The code is based on an example my professor wrote, so I'm not sure why its not displaying right.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] strNames = { "Livonia",
                          "Redford" ,
                          "Novi" ,
                          "Westland",
                          "Northville" };
    int[,] intTemps = new int[5, 4];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            cobNames.Items.Add(strNames[i]);
            lstNames.Items.Add(strNames[i]);
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cobNames.SelectedIndex >= 0 && cobNames.SelectedIndex <= 4)
            {
                if (intTemps[cobNames.SelectedIndex, (int)nudTemp.Value - 1] == 0)
                {
                    intTemps[cobNames.SelectedIndex, (int)nudTemp.Value - 1] = Int32.Parse(txtTemp.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                    DialogResult result;
                    result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to change temps?", "Temps already exist!", buttons);
                    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        intTemps[cobNames.SelectedIndex, (int)nudTemp.Value - 1] = Int32.Parse(txtTemp.Text);
                    }
                }
                displayTemps();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid name!");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Temps must be integers");
        }
    }

    private void displayTemps()
    {
        string strLine;
        lstTemp.Items.Clear();
        double[] dblAverages = new double[5];
        int intNonBlank = 0;

        for (int l = 0; l <= 4; l++)
        {
            intNonBlank = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c <= 3; c++)
            {
                if (intTemps[l, c] != 0)
                {
                    dblAverages[l] += intTemps[l, c];
                    intNonBlank++;
                }
            }
            if (intNonBlank != 0)
            {
                dblAverages[l] /= intNonBlank;
            }
        }
        for (int l = 0; l <= 4; l++)
        {                
            strLine = " ";
            for (int c = 0; c <= 3; c++)
            {
                if (intTemps[l, c] == 0)
                {
                    strLine += "     ";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (intTemps[l, c] == 120)
                    {
                        strLine += intTemps[l, c] + "  ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strLine += intTemps[l, c] + "   ";
                    }
                    lstTemp.Items.Add(strLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your displayTemps() procedure. This wil add to `lstTemp` all information you need:

```
private void displayTemps()
{
    string strLine;
    lstTemp.Items.Clear();
    double[] dblAverages = new double[5];
    int intNonBlank = 0;

    for (int l = 0; l <= 4; l++)
    {
        intNonBlank = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c <= 3; c++)
        {
            if (intTemps[l, c] != 0)
            {
                dblAverages[l] += intTemps[l, c];
                intNonBlank++;
            }
        }
        if (intNonBlank != 0)
        {
            dblAverages[l] /= intNonBlank;
        }
        int min_temp = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 4).
            Select(i => intTemps[l, i]).Min();
        int max_temp = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 4).
            Select(i => intTemps[l, i]).Max();
        lstTemp.Items.Add(
            "Average temp for city "+ l +": " + dblAverages[l] + " " + 
            "Minimum " + min_temp + " " + 
            "Maximum " + max_temp);
    }           
}
```